# Wordpress - Hide Category from Posts

Tags: wordpress

So our Wordpress site's backend is horribly slow due to the HUGE amount of posts we have. There are three categories in particular that we shouldn't need to edit, so I am hoping to not even load them in the back end. I have seen plugins that restrict who can edit what categories of posts, but it doesn't seem to speed it up much. I'm not sure if this is because it is still pulling those posts and just filtering them out when displaying?

I am wondering if `_get_list_table( 'WP_Posts_List_Table' )` has a hook of some sort where I can make it so those three categories are not even pulled from the database.

Is this possible? Would it help speed up the backend?

Thanks!

### Edit:

Kinda want something like this, but set() does not allow modifiers on = or !=

```
function exclude_category_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_admin()) {
        //$query->set( 'cat', '-187460' );
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 187460, 187460, 182149 ) ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );
```

The commented out method only works with one category. The new query doesn't filter anything ):

Comment: Consider asking the question on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286618/exclude-or-include-category-ids-in-wp-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PHP code to exclude WordPress category from blog

```
function exclude_category($query) {
if ( $query->is_home() ) {
$query->set('cat', '-xx');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

The trick is to add the minus sign in front of your category ID (the xx in the example above). Try that, it should work.

Use this notation `$query->set( 'cat', '-60, -61' );` to exclude multiple categories.

### Alternative

You can also use the `category__not_in` parameter

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

[source](https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/exclude-category-wordpress-blog/)

Comment: Could also use the `category__not_in => []` parameter.

Comment: Can I use set() for multiple categories? Seems like it only ignores the last one.

Comment: Use this notation     $query->set( 'cat', '-60, -61' );

Comment: Thanks David that did it